# Unix сокет файл как осуществляется двухнаправленное взаимодействие

Tags: сокет, unix, tcp

Изучаю сокеты, в целом понятно, как работает TCP, но в этом случае есть 2 сокета и каждый процесс пишет только в один, а читает из другого (серверный и клиентский).

Я не совсем понимаю, как работают Unix сокет файлы, которые осуществляют взаимодействие между двумя процессами внутри одного компьютера.
Как физически они и пишут и читают из одного файла?
Или там есть какой то порядок?

Comment: В случае Unix сокетов, файл который его представляет, это просто имя для буферов ядра, используемых для передачи данных (так же, как и IP:Port в случае AF_INET socket). Т.е. физически с диском никто в этом случае не работает.

Comment: Вот тут  -- https://coderoad.ru/5815675/  вроде бы коротенько и по делу

Comment: то что это не физический файл на диске это понятно. А что на счет того что 2 процесса одновременно пишут в сокет, как это физически происходит? Это два разных буфера один для записи первого процесса и чтения второго и наоборот или как?

Comment: @avp, лучше уж на [оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815675) ссылки приводить, а не на очередной мусорный сайт с машинным переводом.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, это первое что подсунул гугл (захочет разобраться, сам поищет по ключевым словам и поймет)

Comment: @ПавелКозлов, да хоть 5 процессов могут писать и читать, если у них есть  файловые дескрипторы. Сокет это двунаправленный канал. С каждой из сторон связан файловый дескриптор. В случае tcp один (серверный) получаете    по accept, другой (клиентский) становится активным по connect. Это можно реализовать как 2 буфера (логически). В один пишет сервер (это м.б. несколько процессов) и из него читает клиент (тоже м.б. несколько процессов).  В другой -- наоборот, пишет клиент (тот что вызывал connect), а читает из него сервер.

Comment: добавлю, что прежде чем начать обмен данными сервер с клиентом (что на tcp-сокете, что на AF_UNIX) устанавливают соединение. и сервер поддерживает с каждым клиентом отдельный двунаправленный канал обмена данными.